# tikz alignment for multi-line text within font commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

Why doesn't `tikz` accept multi-line text within font commands like `\texttt` and `\textbf`?

For instance, compilation of the document

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % this node works
  \node[draw,align=left] (a) {Normal text\\works.};

  % this node gives an error
  \node[draw,align=left] [below of=a] {\texttt{Typewritter text is\\rejected.}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

fails with the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@invoke@collected@onpath ...mmand \tikz@temp 
                                                  \pgf@stop \tikz@node@is@a@...
l.10 ... {\texttt{Typewritter text is\\rejected.}}
```

What is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: You are trying to use a paragraph as an argument to the `\texttt`. You can use `font=\ttfamily` instead as the node option. Also note that TikZ modifies double backslash so it's not directly TeX rules inside a node. In fact, for line breaking inside the node TikZ uses a `minipage`.

Comment: @percusse, would you write an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 4):

Specify the font in the node attributes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,align=left] (a) {Normal text\\works.};
  \node[draw,align=left,font=\ttfamily] [below of=a] {Typewriter text is\\not rejected.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the way to do it! (On your way to the `tikz-pgf` gold badge!)

Comment: @Jake I didn't even look at the manual. ;-) But the present status is "560 [tag:tikz-pgf] × 98", a bit far from the gold badge. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Add `text width` to make the line breakable:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % this node works
  \node[draw,align=left] (a) {Normal text\\works.};

  % this node gives an error
  \node[draw,align=left, text width = 3cm] [below of=a] {\texttt{Typewriter text\\is not rejected.}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That workaround has the disadvantage of specifying an arbitrary text width. I would like to have the node width automatically calculated, as happens with the `a` node in the example.